# VsCode Dart code highlighting wrong colors

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have a very strange issue. After upgrading Flutter yesterday to the newest version, my syntax highlighting is awfully off. When I open a file, everything seems fine, but as soon as the file is analyzed and the result is used for highlighting, everything breaks.

**Correct** (for 1-2 seconds after opening the file):
[image: Correct colors]

**Wrong** (after around 2 seconds):
[image: Wrong colors]

I am using the Monokai Theme for VsCode. I would love to get my old coloring back, as I think the new scheme is outrageously difficult to look at.

My Flutter Doctor outpu (All versions etc.):

```
[flutter] flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.867], locale en-NZ)
    • Flutter version 2.0.3 at R:\Programme\Flutter
    • Framework revision 4d7946a68d (3 days ago), 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
    • Engine revision 3459eb2436
    • Dart version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at R:\Programme\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: R:\Programme\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at R:\Programme\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.54.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.57

• No issues found!
exit code 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I see a lot of "class not recognized" items.  Are you sure your analysis server is launching properly?  the dartcode website tells you how to enable a log.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false` in your vscode `settings.json`

Comment: Thanks! That was going to drive me crazy

Comment: Haha wow, man you're  a life saver. . Thanks a bunch, also @Chris, thanks for the question, searched for hours on stack overflow till finally I landed on exactly what was bothering me

Comment: My man, I was feeling bad with that highlighting everywhere